# erlang race condition of spawn and receive

Tags: erlang

I am learning erlang with book , In chapter 13, the first exercise is writing a function my_spawn, which catch exit message when spawned message crash/exited.

```
-module(my_spawn1).
-compile(export_all).

my_spawn(Mod,Func,Args) ->
    {M1, S1, Mi1} = os:timestamp(),
    Pid = spawn(Mod,Func,Args),
    lib_misc:on_exit(Pid, fun(Why) ->
                  {M2,S2,Mi2} = os:timestamp(),
                  ElapsedTime = (M2 - M1) * 1000000 + (S2 - S1) * 1000 + (Mi2-Mi1),
                  io:format("~p died with:~p~n consume time:~p(ms)", [Pid,Why,ElapsedTime]),
              end),
    Pid.
```

my confuse was, if after spawn_monitor, the `Mod:Func(Args)` was finished, but the `lib_misc:on_exit(...)` haven't setup, so the exit message will be lost, really ?

If that's correct, so how to catch this situation ?

**[edit by Pascal]**

I add the code for lib_misc:on_exit/2

```
on_exit(Pid, Fun) ->
    spawn(fun() -> 
          process_flag(trap_exit, true), %% <label id="code.onexit1"/>
          link(Pid),                     %% <label id="code.onexit2"/>
          receive
              {'EXIT', Pid, Why} ->      %% <label id="code.onexit3"/>
              Fun(Why)   %% <label id="code.onexit4"/>
          end
      end).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing the function on_exit does is to spawn a process that set the process_flag trap_exit to true, thus it is "protected" from crashes, and will receive instead messages of the type: `{'EXIT', Pid, Why}`.

On the next line it tries to link itself to Pid; 2 cases are possible:

- the Pid does not exists (wrong value, already dead...) then the on_exit process will receive the message `{'EXIT', Pid, noproc}` and will call F(noproc).
- the Pid exists, then the on_exit process will wait on receive until the process Pid dies for some Reason. on_exit will receive `{'EXIT', Pid, Reason}` and call F(Reason).

I don't understand why you speak about spawn_monitor, it is not used in your case. Anyway, if you replace link(Pid) by monitor(process,Pid) in the on_exit function, you even don't need to use trap_exit since the monitor function don't crash if the Pid is dead. In all cases it returns the message `{'DOWN',MonitorReference,process,Pid,Reason}`. on_exit could be modified like this:

```
on_exit(Pid, Fun) ->
    spawn(fun() -> 
          MonitorReference = monitor(process,Pid),
          receive
              {'DOWN',MonitorReference,process,Pid,Why} -> Fun(Why)
          end
      end).
```

Comment: good, if the monitor process exit before receive but after create monitor , what happens ?

Comment: I was used monitor, not system process which settings process_flag of trap_exit to truth /

Comment: you are right, noproc or noconnection will be the reason

Comment: does this mean when process created, the mailbox created, even if you don't call receive command on it ?

Comment: Yes, the mailbox is created with the process, it can store incoming messages before any receive statement is reached.

Answer (score 1):

No, the message (like all messages) will be queued. If the process receiving the message dies, though, its mailbox is lost.

If A does `spawn_monitor` to spawn B, and B dies instantly, A is guaranteed to receive the DOWN message. If, however, A also dies, then everything in A's message queue is lost.