# Avoiding a race condition in erlang

Tags: erlang, race-condition

Is this how you avoid a race condition?

```
-module(b).
-export([my_spawn/1]).



my_spawn(Func) ->
    Pid = spawn(listener()),
    Pid ! {self(), spawn, Func},
    receive 
        {From, Desired_Pid} -> Desired_Pid
    end.




listener() ->

    receive 
        {From, spawn, Func} -> 
        {Pid,Ref} = spawn_monitor(Func),
        From ! {self(), Pid},
        receive 
            {'DOWN',Ref, process, _, _} -> io:format("I lived for [calculated how long i lived]")
        end
    end.
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is

```
A = spawn(proc),
monitor(process,A).
```

However A might die before the second line executes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [erlang race condition of spawn and receive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28579698/erlang-race-condition-of-spawn-and-receive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you spawn a process and it dies just before you create your monitor, you will still receive the `DOWN` message:

```
1> Pid = spawn(erlang,now,[]).
<0.35.0>
2> is_process_alive(Pid).
false
3> monitor(process, Pid).
#Ref<0.0.0.86>
4> flush().
Shell got {'DOWN',#Ref<0.0.0.86>,process,<0.35.0>,noproc}
```

As this shell session shows, we first spawn an intentionally short-lived process, and we use `is_process_alive` to verify that it's dead. We then create a monitor for the process, and then we flush the shell's message queue and see that it did indeed receive a `DOWN` message for the already-deceased process.

Comment: So there is no need to go through all the hustle.I was reading in Joe Armstrong's book that if the process dies before we create a link/monitor then the on_exit function (which is just a fun evaluated after the process receives `DOWN` ) will not work as expected. Am I missing something here or were there some updates made to erlang to render this remark useless?

Comment: Links and monitors are two different things. In particular, you do need to avoid race conditions between `spawn` and `link` via `spawn_link`, given that `link` by default causes both linked processes to die if either dies. If process A dies before process B links to it, then B will not die, nor will it receive any exit message if it's trapping exits. As you can see from my answer, though, monitors behave differently.